How to convert UML or HCI diagrams to LTSA format?
I want to implement this paper. Their well-maintained fortis tool takes LTSA format env and sys specification as input. However, I wish to take UML specification as input since it is very commonly used. So I need some process to convert UML(XML) to LTSA.
I googled around the past few days but I could not find any tool that convert UML to LTSA. Not even UML->TLA+/Alloy and TLA+/Alloy->LTSA. Any suggestions would be helpful.
